# How to make changes to OpenJDK and run the program?

Tags: java, javac

I'm working on a new project where I need to alter the java runtime enviroment. I need to edit the OpenJDK implementation a bit (Not making any crazy stuffs) and then run my java program.

I'm not getting how to start with this. Please someone help.

I was going through OpenJDK source code, but not getting a resource where I can start building the program after making changes to the source code and run my java program using the newly built OpenJDK.

I was checking the source code from here: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/

Edit:
I'm using ubuntu 19.04 OS.
I want to know how to build OpenJDK and run java programs with the built JDK instead of the default one.

Comment: You are not supposed to alter the OpenJDK. Even if you did so, and you were to ship the application to a client, he wouldn't have your changes. If you want to change the OpenJDK, become a developer on the OpenJDK project, and request a codechange, and see if they'll allow you to change it

Comment: Wait, you managed to make modifications to the SDK but then you don't know how to run a program with it?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Maybe there is another way to achieve the same thing in Javaland (on top of the regular JDK instead of rolling your own JDK).

Comment: @Stultuske It is for a college project.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes

Comment: @srccode so? you mean to say if you were to have an english assignment for college, it would be okay for you to use non-existent words, as long as you altered the dictionary and put them in?

Comment: @srccode ok. so what specific problem are you having? Building the modified SDK? Running it instead of the default one? Do you have a default one installed? Please, give us more information and a specific problem

Comment: @Stultuske, It is a research project I'm working on where I need to alter a few things in Java run time.

Comment: @srccode changes you should make in YOUR code, not in someone else's code. that's the whole point. You shouldn't go altering the (Open-)JDK

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm not sure how to build one. And also after building how can I use the built sdk instead of default one. I'm not getting any resources (PS. I'm new to this).

Comment: Here are the build instructions for AdoptOpenJDK: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build Or these, which are more upstream: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/master/doc/building.md

Comment: @Stultuske you can't know that. You don't know what the assignment is. For all you know this may be for a PL course.

Comment: @Stultuske I know. But as this is a research project, I need to disable some functionality of jdk and check my own implementation.

Comment: @srccode regarding running it after build, that's more of a general computing question. Also depends on the operating system. As I said, the more info you give (preferably by [edit]ing your question) the better.

Comment: I am upvoting this question now, because building OpenJDK is non-trivial and I cannot find another thread about it here.

Answer (score 1):

I find it reasonably hard to believe any college assignment would require you to alter the runtime. Nonetheless, have a look at following very extensive document on how to build OpenJDK. The document refers to jdk9, I couldn't immediately find a similar reference for jdk11, but maybe it could be of any help:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/tip/common/doc/building.html

As stated in this document, OpenJDK is a complex software project. Building it requires a certain amount of technical expertise, a fair number of dependencies on external software, and reasonably powerful hardware.

After you managed to build a custom version, I assume it's rather trivial to have your program point to this JDK and use it as its runtime.